# Is the word 'It' in 'It's a pity' a referential pronoun?

Tags: pronouns

**Reopen note:**

This question has been marked as a duplicate of a question about so-called weather-*it*. This question here has nothing to do with weather it. It seems from one of the answers that *it* might be from an extraposition construction, or from a referential usage. This has nothing to do with 'weather-*it*' at all.

---

**Question:**

Is the word 'It' in:

> - It's a pity

a pronoun? Or does it just serve as a filler because otherwise there isn't a subject in the sentence?

Is the situation different in the sentence:

- It's a pity you cannot come.

Comment: Why can't it be both?

Comment: You must differentiate between the lexical classification of a word and it's role in a sentence. Yes, *it* is a pronoun, third person, singular, neuter. Yes, it's a subject. But in this idiomatic use, the pronoun doesn't have an antecedent, which one ordinarily expects with pronouns. This is often called a *dummy it* because it's a placeholder meaning vaguely "the situation."

Comment: @deadrat The apostrophe might just work in _it_'s.

Comment: @deadrat A pointer to *dummy pronoun* (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dummy_pronoun) and also a suggestion to look up previous posts in this site itself, would have helped better I suppose. It's a matter of opinion, though.

Comment: @deadrat I don't think it is a dummy it. It refers to what happened or something that was previously mentioned. It's different from "It's sunny" or "It's raining".

Comment: @Kris ***It**'s a matter of opinion though* I see what you did there. I don't suggest that rep-1 users follow such pointers. If they could've, they would've. I certainly don't suggest that rep-1 users search the repository of previous posts. *I'm* afraid to go in there. A matter of opinion, I suppose. As they say, YMMV.

Comment: @Rathony The _it_ in “it's raining” is a particular subtype of dummy pronouns known as ‘weather _it_’ and only used with [impersonal verbs](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impersonal_verb). In “It’s a pity”, the pronoun is a dummy because it has no specific antecedent—all pronouns, including dummies, always have some level of reference, even weather _it_.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet "It's a pity that we don't agree." Some say *it* is a dummy pronoun used in extrapostion, but others say it is a anteposed pronoun that refers to "that we don't agree". What I meant by "It is not dummy" is the *it* in "It's a pity that we don't agree" has a different grammatical function from other types of dummy it such as *weather it*. I think it is a matter of opinion, not grammatical rule.

Comment: Dummy subjects like the so-called "Weather _it_" are semantically empty; they do not represent a semantic argument and hence are non-referential.

Answer (score 3):

Whether it is used as a meaningless syntactic place holder or whether it is a meaningful referential word, the word *it* is always a pronoun. A pronoun is a syntactic category of word and whether or not a particular word has any meaning or not  does not, on its own, change the category of the word.

In the string:

- It's a pity.

the word *it* is probably best understood as a meaningful word that will be understood from the context. However, it could also be analysed as a meaningless subject in an extraposition construction where the extraposed subject has been deleted and is recoverable from the context:

- It's a pity [that you can't come to the party].

In my opinion, however, the first analysis is the best.

Comment: @user210055 My pleasure:)